# i want to display subcategories right under parent category using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have only one table.all category names under one field and parent category field is there. My table structure is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jil_category` (
  `ctg_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ctg_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_section` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_details` text NOT NULL,
  `ctg_status` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_index` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_image` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_dated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_ipadd` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_ldated` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ctg_lipadd` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ctg_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=196 ;
```

If anybody knows the solution,then please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving you an example

```
function menu()
{
    $menus = $this->db->get_where('jil_category', array('ctg_parent'=>0))->result();
    $data = [];
    foreach($menus as $menu)
    {
         $submenu = $this->db->get_where('jil_category',array('ctg_parent'=>$menu->ctg_id));
         if($submenu->num_rows()>0)
             $menu->submenu = $submenu->result();
         else
             $menu->submenu = [];

        $data[] = $menu;
    }
    $menudata['menus'] =$data;
    $this->load->view(index,$menudata);

}
```

**On your View**

```
foreach($menus as $menu)
{ ?>
    <li><?php echo $menu->ctg_name;
         if(!empty($menu->submenu)){ echo '<ul>';
          foreach($menu->submenu as $submenu){ ?>
            <li><?=$submenu->ctg_name?></li>
           <?php } echo '</ul>'; }?>
     </li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. First of all select distinct Parent Categories from Table.
Using foreach you can display all Parent Categories.

Inside foreach loop, make a function in helper/controller, pass the parent_cat_id to that function and now get all the sub cats for that specific category. just like: getSubCategories($parent_cat_id);

if there's some sub categories in the table, the function returns you the data else it returns you nothing.

Let me know if you need anything else and if thats the solution, +1 the answer.

Comment: Vinie has pasted the sample code for you. I told you how it works.